# Dealing with Data from different regions

Tags: date, localization

Does anyone know a good way to deal with Dates from different regions?

I have created some code to automatically analyse and detect exceptions in data from a series of different vendors. 
However some of the information contains dates and so when pasting the data into excel it will sometimes erroneously convert a date from 1 march 12 to the 3 Jan 12 and then not read others.
This is clearly due to the region settings in the computer and excel expecting a date in it's local format.

Does anyone know a good way around this so I can receive dates in either US or European format?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What context are you working in? What technologies are you working with (ie programming language)? Does your data include the region or locale information for each date?

Comment: Apologies I'm working in VBA for excel. I receive an excel sheet from a European customer and then copy the data from that file and paste it into my central file with my macro in it. Some of the dates do not get detected as dates by excel when I paste them in because of the region difference. The File doesn't specify which region it's come from but I can hard code that into my macro's if necessary. The problem I have is it does recognise some dates but the wrong way around and unpicking them then becomes difficult as I have a mix of strings and incorrect dates. Hope that makes more sense

Comment: If it is stored as a date you should be fine, if it's actually stored as a string value you have to do more work.

Answer (score 0):

To change the format if you are in fact dealing with dates you could use the Numberformat on a Range as in:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

If you are dealing with strings it gets a bit more complicated as you have to parse it into a date.